# How to get data gender in Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to show gender using this, but it's not working:

```
foreach($results as $val) {
  $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$val->id.'/?fields=gender';
  $data = json_decode($url,1);
  echo $val->id.' : '.$data->gender;
}
```

Target output:

```
(id : gender)
12345 : male
12346 : female
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. You don't get the content of the URL

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

#### 2. The Facebook API data is contained in a global array which key is `data`.

<strike>`$data->gender;`</strike> should be (both are ok):

- `$data->data->gender;`
- `$data['data']['gender'];`

---

```
foreach($results as $val) {
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$val->id.'/?fields=gender';
    $request = file_get_contents($request_url);
    $json = json_decode($request);
    echo $val->id.' : '.$json->data->gender;
}
```

Comment: Or `$data['data']['gender'];`.

Comment: same bro, empty result

Comment: Oh, I just realized you didn't fetch the URL content. Post updated.

Comment: Also try *with* or *without* the second point. I am not sure anymore about how it is. Thanks.